# CSS TD targeting

Tags: css

How can I apply a style to TDs in a table, except the first row which has headers, and the first column, which has labels.

Basically everything in the second row and second column and beyond.

Comment: check this out https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

Answer (score 2):

As long as there aren't any nested tables, otherwise it requires some modifications:

```
tr:not(:first-of-type) td:not(:first-of-type)
```

EDIT: Fixed previous CSS (sorry).

Updated @apaul34208 's jsfiddle with my own at [codepen](http://codepen.io/WebDevJoshB/pen/epZJNV).

Comment: I was working on something similar, but you beat me to the post. Feel free to use my example in your answer: http://jsfiddle.net/vp1sefda/

Comment: Those two statements dont seem to like one another at the same time.

Comment: Updated with fixed CSS and a link to a demo. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using pure css:

```
tr:first-of-type td,
tr td:first-of-type {
  background: red;
}
```

And the fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/wgbrrg0a/

Basically it's just saying in the first row, select all `td` elements, and for every row after, select only the first `td` element.

---

**Edit: selecting the opposite as asked:** My original answer was with the mindset that the first row and column would be selected. This updated fiddle correctly targets everything that *isn't* the first row or column. Hope this helps! http://jsfiddle.net/wgbrrg0a/1/

Comment: So this is kind of the inverse of what I was looking to to. Instead of targeting the certain elements, I target the opposite elements.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
table td:first-child {
 insert properties here
}
```